# Pluralization bugs in tag merge results

Tags: bug, tags, moderator-tools, plurals, tag-merge-utility

When merging tags as a moderator, you see a popup at the end with the details. It has a pluralization bug:

> total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified

and now that I look again, I notice the preceding line is wrong as well:

> destroying 'improve': [improve] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 ta…

That should be *0 posts*, *0 post histories*, etc.

[image]

Comment: Obligatory Giant S warning. That part of the system is not localized, so it doesn't get any pluralization treatment atm

Comment: Are we going to give moderators an awesome UX?